# pyGTK/GTK filechooser - Is it possible to validate user entry before file or folder is written to disc?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, filechooser

I would like to validate the users choice of folder name in a gtk.FileChooser dialogue when creating a new folder.
I tried connecting to the dialogue 'response' signal, but it is already too late, the new folder will be written to disc.
Is there a way to achieve this other then validate the folder after it is written to disc?

Thanks to Mark... here is the code I'm using:

```
import gtk

def _newFolderDialog(currentFolder=None):

    newDialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title="Create new folder", parent=None, 
        action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_CREATE_FOLDER, 
        buttons= (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL), backend=None)
    newButton = newDialog.add_button(gtk.STOCK_NEW, gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
    if currentFolder is not None:
        newDialog.set_current_folder(currentFolder)

    newButton.connect("pressed", validateChoice, newDialog)

    response = newDialog.run()

    if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        newFolder = newDialog.get_filename()
        newDialog.destroy()
        return newFolder

    elif response == 1: # Validation was not satisfied
        msg = gtk.MessageDialog(parent=None, flags=gtk.DIALOG_MODAL,
            type=gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR, buttons=gtk.BUTTONS_OK, 
            message_format="Try again!")
        msg.run()
        msg.destroy()
        current_folder = newDialog.get_current_folder()
        newDialog.destroy()
        return _newFolderDialog(current_folder)

    elif response == 2: # Ok button was pressed, but with no entry
        current_folder = newDialog.get_current_folder()
        newDialog.destroy()
        return _newFolderDialog(current_folder)

    elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
        newDialog.destroy()
        return None

def validateChoice(button, dialog):
    newFolder = dialog.get_filename()

    if newFolder is None: # The cursor was in the empty text entry box
        dialog.response(2)
    else:
        # If cursor is selecting a folder, lets unselect it, we are intereste
        # in the value in the entry text box.
        dialog.unselect_filename(newFolder) 
        newFolder = dialog.get_filename()

        if newFolder is None: # A folder was selected but empty text entry box
            dialog.response(2)

        ## do some validation, in this case the folder has to start with "/home"
        elif not newFolder.startswith("/home"):  
            dialog.response(1)
        else:
            dialog.response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)

newFolder = _newFolderDialog()
print newFolder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a couple ways of doing this.

One, simply write your own response id handler instead of using gtk.RESPONSE_OK (which to the widget means create the folder).  If you do it this way you'll be responsible for actually creating the folder after validation (os.path.mkdir).

Two, you could override the click on the "new" button:

```
import gtk

def new_button_pressed(widget, data=None):
    ## data is a reference to the dialog widget
    ## do some validation, in this case the folder has to start with "/home"
    if not(data.get_filename().startswith("/home")):
        ## force cancel response
        print "failed validation..."        
        data.response(gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL)
    else:
        print "success validation..."
        data.response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)

newDialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog(
title="Create new folder", parent=None, 
action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_CREATE_FOLDER, 
buttons= (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL), backend=None)
new_button = newDialog.add_button(gtk.STOCK_NEW, gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
new_button.connect("pressed", new_button_pressed, newDialog)
newDialog.run()
```

Comment: Thanks! After a few hours of tweaking to account for different possible user actions, I believe I have it. New code posted in question.